# What is up with the different repositories and URLs?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I've got 2 rpis running bullseye, one recently installed and one image from a couple of months ago. The `sources.list` file changed dramatically.

My old installation:

```
# sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye main contrib non-free firmware rpi
# raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspverrypi.org/debian/ bullseye main
```

The other one:

```
# sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
# raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ bullseye main
```

I'm curious what the different repositories are and if my older rpi is missing some repositories. Also what repositories are interchangable and is there any mirror to the `http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/` repo?

Comment: you can examine the content of the repositories with a web browser

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you have installed Raspberry Pi OS 64bit on the newer Pi.

This uses the standard Debian ARM64 repository not the Raspbian.

The firmware is still provided by *Raspberry Pi Ltd.* and the source is the same for 32/64 bit

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ bullseye main
```